How to pass tracking parameters from browser to app? (From a QR code scan)
I wonder if anyone can help me with this?
Scenario:
User scans a QR code and are brought to a web page, where they can download an app. The QR code contains tracking parameters
User then opens the app on their device
When the user opens the app, we lose the tracking from that initial QR code scan, which brought them to the web page.
Is it possible to transfer those tracking parameters from web page to app? Either through code implementation or through a third party tracking tool?
It will give us full E2E visibility for this particular journey.

please help me understand this better, so you want to track it when user installs/opens a different/new app by scanning a QR code from a webview in your react native app?

it is a bit weird take but I think you can achieve it.
The requirement states that the whole flow needs to end on the website, what you can do is open the app via a deep link from the webpage and pass the data you want.
Scenario 1

The user opens the web page
Download the app
Installs the app
Opens the app - Here you see that the app is not opened from a deep link
Redirect back the user to the webpage and open the app from there.

You can play with the flows as much as you want, I hope you get the idea.
Scenario 2 (More complicated)

Have the user register before downloading the app
After the download starts send the data from the QR code to a backend server of your choice
Once you open the app fetch the data from the QR.

